# How to count in a one hot tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I know I can convert a Tensor to the one-hot using this command:

`one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels,depth=3)`

Now I want to count how many of class 0, class 1, and class 2 are there in the `one_hot_labels`. What is the easiest way to count that?

Example:

Input:

```
one_hot_labels = [[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
one_hot_labels.count([1,0,0]) # something like this command
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
one_hot_labels = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
count_label = tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels, axis=0)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(count_label)
# array([2, 0, 1])
```

Now for example you can just do:

```
count_label = tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels, axis=0)[0]
# 2
```